# Finding the highest score from a file

Tags: python-3.x

The code i have designed searches for the highest score per level, The file has multiple lines which are in the order [playername,level,score]. I used this to replace 0 in a variable with the highest score per level then print the highest scores. However, it just prints 0,0,0,0,0
The code is:

```
    current_1 = 0
    current_2 = 0
    current_3 = 0
    current_4 = 0
    current_5 = 0
    FileOpen = open("playerScores.txt")
    FileList = FileOpen.readlines()
    def ScoreBoard  ():
        for item in list(FileOpen):
            CheckLevel = FileList(item,1)
            CheckScore = Filelist(item,2)
            if CheckLevel == 1:
                if CheckScore > current_1:
                    current_1 = CheckScore             
            elif CheckLevel == 2:
                if CheckScore > current_2:
                    current_2 = CheckScore
            elif CheckLevel == 3:
                if CheckScore > current_3:
                    current_3 = CheckScore
            elif CheckLevel == 4:
                if CheckScore > current_4:
                    current_4 = CheckScore
            elif CheckLevel == 5:
                if CheckScore > current_4:
                    current_5 = CheckScore

    ScoreBoard
    print(current_1,current_2,current_3,current_4,current_5)
```

Comment: Probably won't fix your problem, but each of the `if checkLevel... ` `if checkScore... ` pairs could be combined into 1 line if you connect them with an `&&`. It may also prove advantageous to store the current highscore per level in a list to cut down on all the repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) three problems with your code:

- you never actually call your `ScoreBoard` method (missing `()`)
- you create new local variables `current_X` instead of using the `global` ones
- after reading all the lines from the file, the `FileOpen` iterator is exhausted
- not sure what `FileList(item,1)` is supposed to be, but it won't give you the second item in the line

You could try like this:

```
def ScoreBoard  ():
    global current_1, current_2, ..., current_5
    for item in FileList: # read from the lines, not from the file
        CheckLevel = item.split(",")[1]
        # ... more code
ScoreBoard() # mind the ()
```

And there are some more things you might want to improve:

- you put the scores for all the players into the same variables; maybe add the name of the player as a parameter?
- instead of using individual variables for each score, use a dictionary
- instead of using global variables, return the dictionary from the function
- use `with` for opening files

Something like this:

```
def scoreboard(name):

    all_scores = {}
    with open("playerScores.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            player, level, score = line.split(",")
            if player == name and score > all_scores.get(level, 0):
                all_scores[level] = int(score)
    return all_scores

current = scoreboard("name of some player")
print(current)
```

Comment: I did both of your fixes, but the output is still 0,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not calling `ScoreBoard`, and even if you do, you've already read your file, when you do `FileList = FileOpen.readlines()`, so when you try to do `list(FileOpen)`, you get an empty list. Of course that's a good thing, since `FileList(item, 1)` and `FileList(item, 2)` isn't going to work very well.

A nice way to check if your code is doing what it should is by using the logging module:

```
import logging

log = logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


current_1 = 0
current_2 = 0
current_3 = 0
current_4 = 0
current_5 = 0

FileOpen = open("playerScores.txt")
FileList = FileOpen.readlines()

def ScoreBoard  ():
    log.debug(">> ScoreBoard")
    for item in list(FileOpen):
        log.debug("Checking item %s", item)
        CheckLevel = FileList(item,1)
        CheckScore = Filelist(item,2)
        if CheckLevel == 1:
            if CheckScore > current_1:
                current_1 = CheckScore             
        elif CheckLevel == 2:
            if CheckScore > current_2:
                current_2 = CheckScore
        elif CheckLevel == 3:
            if CheckScore > current_3:
                current_3 = CheckScore
        elif CheckLevel == 4:
            if CheckScore > current_4:
                current_4 = CheckScore
        elif CheckLevel == 5:
            if CheckScore > current_4:
                current_5 = CheckScore

log.debug("Calling ScoreBoard")
ScoreBoard
log.debug("Done with ScoreBoard")
print(current_1,current_2,current_3,current_4,current_5)
```

However, you can drastically improve the readability of your program:

```
import logging

log = logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

current_1 = 0
current_2 = 0
current_3 = 0
current_4 = 0
current_5 = 0


def scoreboard():
    log.debug('>> scoreboard')
    with open("playerScores.txt") as f:
        log.info('Reading scores...')
        for line in f:
            level, score = line.strip().split()
            level = int(level)
            score = int(score)
            log.debug('level: %s score: %s', level, score)

            if level == 1 and score > current_1:
                log.debug('Level 1 high score: %s', score)h
                current_1 = score
            elif level == 2 and score > current_2:
                log.debug('Level 2 high score: %s', score)
                current_2 = score
            elif level == 3 and score > current_3:
                log.debug('Level 3 high score: %s', score)
                current_3 = score
            elif level == 4 and score > current_4:
                log.debug('Level 4 high score: %s', score)
                current_4 = score
            elif level == 5 and score > current_5:
                log.debug('Level 6 high score: %s', score)
                current_5 = score

    log.debug("<< scoreboard")


scoreboard()
print(current_1,current_2,current_3,current_4,current_5)
```